# Does this ray fall inside this angle?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, angle

I'm writing a routine to judge if an angle $\varphi$ in a plane lies in the smaller of the two angles formed by two other rays at angles $\varphi_1$ and $\varphi_2$. The angles *aren't* bounded in $\left[0,2\pi\right)$.

The usual convention is followed: the $0$ angle lies on the positive half of $x$ axis, and increasing angle goes counter-clockwise. In the diagram $\varphi$ lies in the convex angle while $\varphi'$ doesn't.

[image: An illustration]

I'm thinking that since $\varphi$ is "*between*" $\varphi_1$ and $\varphi_2$, this relation has to hold
$$\sin(\varphi-\varphi_1)\sin(\varphi_2-\varphi)>0, \tag{1}$$

because the two sine values have the same sign. However, some angles in the concave side (the bigger angle) can also satisfy this by forming two obtuse angles, so (1) isn't good.

I would appreciate your ideas on a sound and simple mathematical method.

Comment: Can you please provide a diagram?

Comment: Using vector calculus -- unit vector in direction $\phi$ being in the same half-plane as the sum of unit vectors for directions $\phi_1$ and $\phi_2$ -- gives $$\cos(\phi)\left ( \cos(\phi_1) + \cos(\phi_2) \right ) + \sin(\phi)\left( \sin(\phi_1) + \sin(\phi_2)\right) \gt 0$$Would this be simple and sound enough?

Comment: @NominalAnimal I don't think it stands because $\varphi'$ can also be in the same half-plane as $\varphi$. For instance, by only moving the $\varphi'$ in the diagram such that 1. it remains on the concave side but 2. being very close to $\varphi_1$.

Comment: Tell us exactly how the two rays are given. The statements $\phi_i\in{\mathbb R}$ don't sound very cultured.

Comment: @ChristianBlatter Example: $\varphi_1=\frac{\pi}{4}+2m\pi$, $\varphi_2=-\frac{3}{4}\pi+2n\pi$, where $m,n\in\mathbb N$. The reason I specify $\varphi\in\mathbb R$ is due to the input I need for a program routine. I wish a combination of trigonometry will be good enough but I'm stuck here. I could use cumbersome methods such as making $\varphi_1$ and $\varphi_2$ differ not more by $\pi$, but I like to see some trigonometry. I removed the $\in\mathbb R$ wording.

Comment: @FrenzyLi: Ah, you're right; it always accepts a full half-plane, even if the angle is much smaller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have three 2D vectors:
$$\begin{align}
\vec{u} &= (\cos \phi_1, \sin \phi_1) \\
\vec{v} &= (\cos \phi_2, \sin \phi_2) \\
\vec{p} &= (\cos \phi, \sin \phi) \end{align}$$
The 2D analog of cross product is zero if the vectors are parallel (or opposite), positive if the vectors are listed in counterclockwise order, and negative if the vectors are in clockwise order, with their angle always measured the short way round.

This means that if and only if the signs of
$$\begin{matrix}
\vec{u} \times \vec{v} &=& \cos\phi_1 \sin\phi_2 &-& \cos\phi_2 \sin\phi_1 &=& \sin(\phi_2 - \phi_1) \\
\vec{u} \times \vec{p} &=& \cos\phi_1 \sin\phi &-& \cos\phi \sin\phi_1 &=& \sin(\phi - \phi_1) \\
\vec{p} \times \vec{v} &=& \cos\phi \sin\phi_2 &-& \cos\phi_2 \sin\phi &=& \sin(\phi_2 - \phi)
\end{matrix}$$
are the same, then $\vec{p}$ is between $\vec{u}$ and $\vec{v}$, and correspondingly $\phi$ is between $\phi_1$ and $\phi_2$.

Comment: Both answers are equally good. I keep forgetting about cross products, and by marking this as accepted I hope I could always keep it in mind.

Answer (score 1):

Your data amount to the following: You are given two primary directions ${\bf w}_1:=(\cos\phi_1,\sin\phi_1)$ and ${\bf w}_2:=(\cos\phi_2,\sin\phi_2)$, whereby it is assumed that $\phi_1\ne\phi_2$ $(\pi)$, and an "arbitrary" direction ${\bf r}=(\cos\phi,\sin\phi)$. The direction ${\bf r}$ is called *between* ${\bf w}_1$ and ${\bf w}_2$ if $${\bf r}=\lambda_1 {\bf w}_1+\lambda_2{\bf w}_2\tag{1}$$ with $\lambda_1>0$ and $\lambda_2>0$. Solving $(1)$ for $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ gives
$$\lambda_1={\sin(\phi_2-\phi)\over\sin(\phi_2-\phi_1)},\qquad \lambda_2={\sin(\phi-\phi_1)\over\sin(\phi_2-\phi_1)}\ .$$
Therefore we obtain the following criterion: The direction ${\bf r}$ is  between ${\bf w}_1$ and ${\bf w}_2$ **iff** the three numbers
$$\sin(\phi_2-\phi), \quad \sin(\phi-\phi_1), \quad \sin(\phi_2-\phi_1)$$
all have the same sign.

If the ${\bf w}_i$ and ${\bf r}$ are given coordinatewise as
$${\bf w}_1=(u_1,v_1),\quad {\bf w}_2=(u_2,v_2),\quad {\bf r}=(x,y)$$
then the criterion is simple that the three determinants
$$v_2x-u_2y,\quad u_1y-v_1x,\quad u_1v_2-u_2v_1$$
should have the same sign.

Comment: Very solid answer. Thank you for giving an expression for _being between_ here.